# Wireframe tool for WordPress theme

Tags: theme-development

I want to develop a WordPress theme from scratch. Is there any wireframe tool in which I can design the a complete page and it exports the html/php file against it. I want a free tool.

Comment: This is for anyone that finds this old thread: I would go with a framework like Genesis and build a child theme. You can sell the child theme as your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally do not know of any free tool that would achieve what you are looking for. The closest thing would be to use a "slice and chop" company that would take your designs and slice them up for you at a price though.

There is a great "blank" wordpress theme out [there](http://digwp.com/2010/02/blank-wordpress-theme/) that I use on all of my projects. It has all of the files you need for a theme, with most (if not all) of the queries that you need. All you have to do is pretty much style it.

However, the Wordpress Codex is a great resource for learning all the nuts and bolts of wordpress.  I know it has been a life saver to me over the years.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this [website weaver](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/the-website-weaver/)

Website weaver is no longer free, it changed to [spiderweb press](http://www.spiderwebpress.com/) which is 
125$

Comment: you should include more. This answer lacks alot its just a link.

Answer (score -2):

The only one I know is [Artisteer](http://www.artisteer.com/). It's a commercial product but it offers a [free trial](http://www.artisteer.com/?p=downloads). Here's [a demo](http://www.artisteer.com/?p=wordpress_themes) of how it can be used specifically for creating Wordpress themes.

You could also start a theme with the help of [Wordpress Theme Generator](http://www.yvoschaap.com/wpthemegen/).

Answer (score -2):

I have purchased [Artisteer](http://goo.gl/8i01H), and am quite happy with it, in the latest version 3.1 which was just released, they added a lot of essential features (to me) and improved the basic template (reduced complexity and other improvements).

You can download a fully featured version, the generated theme comes filled with preview images, but you can see how it works and if it works for you.

However, it is not a wireframe tool at all, it is just a tool to create visually pleasing templates for many CMS systems (or pure HTML), it helps the non-creative folk generate a neat looking website without tearing their hair out. The major feature for us graphically challenged is the "Suggest" feature, which is the main base of the app.

And for the price, there is nothing quite like it... Give it a try.

Comment: Artisteer produces pretty bad code and uses outdated deprecated functions.

Comment: I agree that Artisteer is not a very compliant tool, however, being as design challenged as I am, I do appreciate the fact that it allows me to arrive at a design without knowing design. By using a combination of random offers from Artisteer and selecting elements I like and still being able to further customize the look.
After some experience I've had with Wordpress, I now use the ideas to create my own theme, not using Artisteer code at all - just the inspiration....